# Looping scikit-learn machine learning datasets

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

How to use `datasets.load_DATASET_NAME` with every string from the `Datasets` array when looping to apply some ML algorithms on one dataset at a time.

I have the following sample program:

```
from sklearn import datasets

_Datasets_=['iris' , 'breast_cancer' , 'wine' , 'diabetes', 'linnerud' , 'boston' ]

for Dataset_name in _Datasets_:
# Load the dataset
  Dataset = datasets.load_'DATASET_NAME'()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a dictionary of names to function names. Then call as you are iterating

```
Datasets = {'data1':load_data_1}

Data = Datasets['data1']()
```